# Am I limited to value types when using AddWebAllowedObject?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

When using AddWebAllowedObject to expose a C# component to Javascript in my WebView, do the function parameters and return types all need to be value types?  Or is it possible to pass object structures?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not limited to value types.

You can refer to the [official example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/WebView). It's a JS project, but you can do the same in c# project. Here are the interest code you can refer and search:

Code where call AddWebAllowedObject:

```
document.getElementById("webview").addWebAllowedObject("winRTSharedObject", winRTSharedObject);
```

Code in HTML:

```
<body class="win-type-body">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <script>
    if (window.winRTSharedObject !== undefined) {
    winRTSharedObject.checkPrimesInRange();
    } else {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = "\'winRTSharedObject\' object doesnt exists";
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Code in c++ winrt component:

```
WinRTSharedObject::WinRTSharedObject()
{
}

void WinRTSharedObject::CheckPrimesInRange()
{
    vector<int> numsVector;

    for (int num = startNumber; num <= endNumber; num++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(num))
        {
            numsVector.push_back(num);
            NotifyAppOfPrimes(num);
        }
    }

    int* numsArray = &numsVector[0];
    //return numsArray;
}
```

Comment: All the parameters in those examples (setStartNumber, setEndNumber, NotifyAppOfPrimes) look to be value types.

Comment: What kind of object or structure you want to pass to c# component? Can you show me a sample? If you want to let c# component can directly understand js complex object or structure, that's impossible. What we can do is to parse them to the object or structure you expected in c#.

Comment: Have you tried the parameters with dynamic object? Then you can use the object's value to instantiate your predefined c# class.

Comment: I was wondering whether there is a way to pass a simple JSON object and have it map to a C# object that has matching properties, or vice versa.  It sounds like the answer is no, you can only pass strings, ints, etc and then build them back into objects on the receiving side.

Comment: For me, it's YES. JSON is text format. For c# it's string. The difference is, if you assign a json format string to javascript object, it knows it is a JSON, because JSON is a subset of javascript. But for c#, we need to serialize or deserialize.